# Google Map not showing in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I used Firebase Test Lab Robo Test to test my application and I found the map is not showing

[image]

I know it looks like I didn't properly set up the package names and SHA1s of my Maps API. But the truth is:

1. My Google Maps API is enabled
2. The package name and the SHA1 of keystore files are added in API settings (both debug and release)
3. The map can be showed on my real devices as well as the emulator in Android Studio

Any ideas?

Comment: does it show any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 11/2023: The re-signing doesn't seem to happen any more. The SHA-1 signature doesn’t change.

—

I suspect that Firebase Test Lab re-signs your app for testing, and therefore changes the SHA-1 signature.

The Google Play pre-launch report, which is based on Firebase Test Lab, mentions that the [app will be re-signed in its docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en#settings):

> As of October 2017, the pre-launch report uses a new crawler to provide a more comprehensive review of your app. To do so, the pre-launch report must temporarily re-sign your APK or app bundle within our test environment.

Comment: then how could be test the location if the app depends on it?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and solve it by deactiving the Firebase Test Lab re-signs:

> Pre-launch reports are automatically generated when you publish an app to the open, closed, or internal test track. To disable all pre-launch reports for your app:
>
> Sign in to your Play Console.
>
> Select an app.
>
> Select Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings.
>
> Next to "Enable pre-launch reports," move the switch to the left until it turns gray. If you want to turn pre-launch reports on again at a later time, move the switch back to the right until it turns blue.

Comment: Is this turning off re-signs or all launch reports altogether?

Comment: do I need to upload a new app bundle then?  I clicked the checkbox for "Turn on pre-launch report" but it hasn't helped yet.  Maybe I need to rebuild to resign?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Playstore launch reports(which is based on Firebase Test Lab)
The APK or bundle is re-signed with their test environment, however there is no direct way to get the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint, I tried contacting googleplay developer support they could not help.

Solution(Workaround) submit a build with a simple Toast message for the SHA-1 in your splash screen and in the next pre-launch report, copy the SHA-1 you see to your API settings

Please refer to this answer on how to get the SHA-1 programmatically
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791043/2936688