# E/FirebaseInstanceId( 5789): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation

Tags: firebase, api, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

While trying to connect Android Studio with a flutter project to Firebase, this error code appeared. After doing A LOT of research, I tried to change my thing, but none seemed to work. I changed my emulator from API 28 to 26 to R, with Nexus 5X which supports Google Play Services. Afterwards, I also added firebase_auth code and cloud_firestore code to pubspec.yaml but it didn't work either. I also tried to change the emulator to Cold Boot but that didn't help. I am really stuck, please HELP!!! Thx :)

Comment: This indicates that the emulator isn't able to connect to the internet. I had the same issue and this answer worked for me [Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706333/235671)

Comment: See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70428443/5721702. You might have forgotten to install Google Play services in your SDK Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Per [GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63290), this error is actually not related to Flutter. In fact, there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1286) in Firebase regarding this error. You can check the [recommended workarounds here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1286#issuecomment-643778402).

Comment: Its not working only for my mobile, I've tried with another two-three devices and it is working perfectly. What should be the reason?