# Flutter java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting "FIS_AUTH_ERROR" error when using the release build but in debug build not getting any issue, it's working completely in last week but today I'm getting this error. I have search lot's of think and getting solution but it's not be work in my end. below I'm mention the which solution I have try.

1 [First solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60698697).
2 [Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67456950).

I have try both above solution but it's not working my end.

Error code line:

```
var _deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Now, If I'm create the Signed APK and install directly So it's working but when I install the build from Play store so getting issue.
Please help me for this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue not able to generate `fcm device token` in android but it was working fine in ios.

I checked `web api key` in the firebase console it was different than what I had in google-servies.json so i just replace json file api key with firebase.

And it worked.

Comment: day-05, and this worked. thanks @rahul-sharma. 
But I'm still confused why API key was from the google cloud, and why this firebase key and google console key are different.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 day's I have found the solution. I have take SHA-1 from Google developer console(App integrity) and add in Google cloud console project and also set inside Firebase project and updated Google-service.json file use.

Comment: Hello @Alpit Panchal, where exactly in Google cloud console and in Firebase did you add the SHA-1 please ?

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue and solved it by going google cloud console -> credentials and -> restore deleted credentials. Actually google auto deleted my api key.