# FirebaseMessaging returns empty token

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FirebaseMessagingService class to generate FCM token on function `onNewToken()`. Some devices will get a token when its fresh installed or after app updated. But on some device, `onNewToken()` return empty token.
When the app doesn't have a token, so I put this code to generate FCM token :

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
  if (!task.isSuccessful || task.result.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Throwable(task.exception))
  }
}
```

I checked on the crashlytics, lot of devices are not getting the FCM token even the devices have Google Play service in it. The exceptions are variative. Here is exception from the crashlytics :

```
- java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
- java.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
- java.io.IOException: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR
```

I also put

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
```

but still not working

Anyone have a same problem?

Comment: Have you added the .json file to your project?

Comment: @MihaiBC do you mean google-services.json? Yes.

Comment: yea, that is the one.

Comment: Can there be any chance that your API key is expired? Is it a new one or something that you have been using for a while?

Comment: Also check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60698697/8208808 , Maybe it will help you

Comment: @MihaiBC it's happening only on some devices, most devices are still getting fcm token. so i think it's not from the api key.