# How to get token from FCM in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I want use FCM and I added below dependencies in gradle file :

```
//Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
//Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.3'
```

I write below codes but after run application not show me token and just show error in logcat! 
In FCM console I created json file for my application and paste it in my project! 
**My Activity code:**

```
//FCM
Log.e("FirebaseToken", "1");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    Log.e("FirebaseToken", "2");
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.e("FirebaseToken", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
        return;
    }
    String token = task.getResult();
    Log.e("FirebaseToken", "Token : " + token);
});
```

**Service codes:**

```
public class MyFcmService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        Log.e("FirebaseToken", "Refreshed token: " + token);
    }
}
```

After run application show me this messages in logcat:

```
1
2023-06-28 10:07:03.962 16810-16810 FirebaseToken           com.myapp                          E  2
2023-06-28 10:07:03.964 16810-16810 FirebaseToken           com.myapp                          E  Fetching FCM registration token failed
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:625)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:392)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FirebaseMessaging$hhRqCIwb_q-GasIrdNMReoTbQ60.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:623)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:392) 
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FirebaseMessaging$hhRqCIwb_q-GasIrdNMReoTbQ60.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse(GmsRpc.java:309)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(GmsRpc.java:320)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$GmsRpc$tPjltVSAbk36mmkzOG1vcfMBmQo.then(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$_14QHG018Z6p13d3hzJuGTWnNeo.execute(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:14)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.IOException: FIS\_AUTH\_ERROR in Android Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698622/java-io-ioexception-fis-auth-error-in-android-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

try this one!

gradle file(appLevel)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
```

Manifest File Add:

```
         <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Service codes:

```
public class MyFirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.e(Utils.TAG, token);
    }
}
```

My Activity code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {
                        Log.e("fcmToken:=>",s);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to get token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```