# Push notification raised the error FIS_AUTH_ERROR in a MAUI app

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, maui

I want to add in my `.NET8` `MAUI` a push notification using the `Azure Notification Hub`. I created a new app in Firebase and copied the *google-services.json* in the project. The notification was working for a while and then suddenly stopped working both in a real device or in an emulator.

The error I get is the following one:

> Java.IO.IOException: 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR'

[image]

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698622/java-io-ioexception-fis-auth-error-in-android-firebase). I checked the *google-services.json* and there is a `current_key` in the `api_key`. Differently from the issue in the post, the application is working on a physical device but not in an emulator.

This is the call stack

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

### Update

I ran the app a couple of times and it was working. Then, suddenly, not. With a `try catch` I get these details

> LanguageInUse.Platforms.Android.Notification.DeviceInstallationService.RegisterDevice(String
> notificationHubNamespace, String notificationHub, String key) in
> C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\Notification\DeviceInstallationService.cs:line
> 30   --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
> java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR   at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:626)
> at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:382)
> at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda9.run(Unknown
> Source:4)     at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:2)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException:
> FIS_AUTH_ERROR    at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:5)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:8)
> at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:624)
> ... 9 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR   at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse(GmsRpc.java:309)
> at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$com-google-firebase-messaging-GmsRpc(GmsRpc.java:320)
> at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.then(Unknown
> Source:2)     at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:3)
> at
> androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(Unknown
> Source:0)     at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:5)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:3)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:8)
> at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown
> Source:0)     at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:5)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:3)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:3)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzr.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:2)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.0.0:14)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

Comment: According to your updated introduction, do you mean the notification function back to normal and crashed again?