# Plugin.LocalNotification causes the error FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: c#, android, maui

In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I added the push notification using *Firebase* (Firebase.Messaging). The application is working, and the device is registered to the `Azure Notification Hub`. Now, I like to display the message using the `Plugin.LocalNotification`.

When I add the plugin, I get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78034383/push-notification-raised-the-error-fis-auth-error-in-a-maui-app)

> Java.IO.IOException: 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR'

[image]

The plugin in a way is interfering with the device registration in Firebase. The error occurs when this line is executed:

```
var firebaseToken = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

I'm sure it is something related to the plugin. If I remove the plugin, the app is working, and the device can be registered.

How can I fix this issue?